# Can someone clear up some confusion on how to use twitter bootstrap and Angular 4 together?

Tags: jquery, angular, bootstrap-4

So I've been dabbling with Angular (4.x.x) and I wanted to use twitter bootstrap cause it looks nice.

Here's where the confusion starts:
Bootstrap requires jQuery.  However, the consensus seems to be, don't use jQuery in an Angular app.

So, there seems to be some GitHub projects that have native Angular code to take jQuery out of the equation.

I look into `ng-bootstrap`, and head over to their docs on how to install it.  All goes well, except the CSS styles aren't included, nor does the docs tell you how to get the CSS styles in.  Seems like a basic necessity for a "Getting Started" guide, but whatever.

So I do some Google-fu and find a clean looking, more complete guide on how to get `ng-bootstrap` installed AND the styles.

https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/using-bootstrap-with-angular-c83c3cee3f4a

Then I get to the paragraph that has me doing the Jackie Chan meme..

> Ng-Bootstrap contains a set of native Angular directives based on Bootstrap’s markup and CSS. As a result no dependency on jQuery or Bootstrap’s JavaScript is required.
>   ...
>   Now add bootstrap.min.css, jquery.min.js and bootstrap.min.js to you .angular-cli.json file, like we did it before.

If `ng-bootstrap` is supposed to remove the need for jquery and boostrap JS, why am I adding the bootstrap.min.js and jquery.min.js?!

I can't find a reasonable explanation. Can someone please clear up this confusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When people say you don't want to use jquery in your Angular projects, they mean directly in your components or html. Using third party npm modules is completely fine, and bootstrap can be quickly and easily integrated into your Angular environment in a clean and safe way. I'd highly recommend you use Angular-CLI if you're not already.

Simply `npm install --save boostrap`, and then include the css files and scripts required in your your **.angular-cli.json**.

```
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
    "styles.scss"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ],
```

*note:* As you mentioned even these "Angular bootstrap" modules are using the jquery and bootstrap css, and from my experience bring absolutely nothing new to the table. They may have had a use back when Angular and bootstrap were evolving quickly side by side, but nowadays are more work with no reward.

Comment: This makes the resources I've run across more clear. It appears I've jumped in the deep end by trying to learn some of the 'bleeding edge' libraries, with no previous experience with javascript / npm / jquery, etc.  Thank you.

Comment: There are *tons* of packages that say 'angular this' or 'angular that', and 90% of the time they're unnecessary. Most of the core packages in npm can either be used like this, or simply by adding the typings with the package `npm install --save-dev @types/{{package-name}}`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to add bootstrap.min.js or jquery.min.js to use ng-bootstrap. Please check following link.

https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

Anyhow bootstrap is using jquery internally. It does not mean you need to use it in your components, directives etc. And using jquery inside angular is strongly discouraged.

**Edit**

For the Confusion:

ng-bootstrap contains a set of native Angular directives based on Bootstrap's markup and CSS. As a result **no dependency on jQuery or Bootstrap's JavaScript is required**. The only required dependencies are:

Angular

Bootstrap CSS

[ng-bootstrap getting started](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started)

Comment: This is incorrect.  Bootstrap is dependent upon it's own javascript and jQuery components.

Comment: Yes, bootstrap is dependent on javascript and jQuery. I never said it don't. I said you don't have to add jQuery into the angular application if you use ng-bootstrap. bootstrap will be using it internally. Sir please refer the documentation of ng-bootstrap

Comment: I did read the documentation and I asked for clarification on that documentation (which refers general question to be asked in SO).

Comment: ng-bootstrap and bootstrap are two different things. ng-bootstrap has Angular components that are build using traditional bootstrap library. Traditional bootstrap library uses jquery where ng-bootstrap uses Angular style method.If you use traditional bootstrap library, soon or later you will need to use Jquery in your application. E.g. Scrollspy. By "traditional bootstrap library" I mean directly importing bootstrap to Angular application as @Z. Bagley mentioned. It works, But it is not the perfect method since ng-bootstrap exists.

Comment: It's starting to make more sense.  "Traditional" -> install bootstrap and its dependencies.  "Ng-Bootstrap" -> install Ng-Bootstrap and its dependencies (which includes bootstrap and ITS dependencies) but that does not mean install jQuery as a dependency to Angular directly.  Do I got it now?

Comment: Ng-Bootstrap contains a set of native Angular directives based on Bootstrap's markup and CSS. As a result no dependency on jQuery or Bootstrap's JavaScript is required. The only required dependencies are:

Angular and Bootstrap CSS [Ng-Bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started)

Comment: So basically the documentation was incomplete and therefore it was confusing. My question has been answered, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In your app Angular in the file .angular-cli.json put this

```
 "styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
  ]
```

you must installed npm packgage of bootstrap

I hope that it helps you

Comment: As my understanding he is not asking how to integrate bootstrap into angular 4 project. He is asking why is it integrate with jquery.

Comment: You are right, he is asking why it have included the min.js